# Set font-family to specific symbols in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

On my website i use non standard cyrillic font. It looks well but it have problems with some special symbols, for example - quotes (for some reason opening and ending quote look different).

I would like to set font-family for specific symbols using CSS. Is it possible?

Comment: Share your code which done...

Comment: please specify what code do you need to answer this question?

Comment: whichever done by you...

Comment: i don't have code solving this problem. That is why i am asking.

Comment: Yes, it is - [**Unicode Range Font Face**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)

Comment: @Paulie_D That's awesome... I had no idea you could do that!

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you - it looks like what i am searching for. But it is not this code is not working @ font-face {
  font-family: Arial;
  src: local('Arial'); 
  unicode-range: U+0025-00FF, U+4??, U+0022, U+00AB, U+00BB;
}
maybe you make it as  full answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manage this using a unicode range `@font-face` rule

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)

I'm unsure as to how well this demo will work in a Snippet as it will depend on you have the designated font installed. However, in general, it's something like this:

```css
@font-face {

  font-family: 'Algerian';
  src: local('Algerian');
  unicode-range: U+022-026;

}

div {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: Algerian, sans-serif;

}

div {
  text-align: center;

}

p {
  font-size: 72px;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>" Lorem & Ipsum "</p>
</div>
```

In this instance I've applied the rule to open & closed quotes and the ampersand.

**Support**: [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-unicode-range)

For Firefox though:

> Support can be enabled in Firefox using the layout.css.unicode-range.enabled flag

Comment: For me the whole sentence/copy is in Algerian font family. Using Firefox

Comment: It's a shame that FF doesn't support this, otherwise a perfect answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D really great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your symbols to a new font then you'll have to wrap them in a tag and assign a class...

in your CSS add a class for the font

```
.symbol {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Then in your HTML you will need to use this class on your symbols...

```
    <p>Jesse Jackson? Do you even... ah, I see you have a telephone at least. You know that blinking thing I've been calling you on? 
<i class="symbol">"<i>I will break this, I will BREAK THIS.<i class="symbol">"<i> </p>
```

## If the problem is only for quotes?

You could set the `:before` and `:after` pseudo for a `<blockquote></blockquote>`, which could be set to a icon font. Perhaps fontawesome?

```css
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
blockquote:before {
  content: "\f10d";
  left: -1em
}
blockquote:after {
  content: "\f10e";
  right: -1em
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="stylesheet">

<blockquote>Jesse Jackson? Do you even... ah, I see you have a telephone at least. You know that blinking thing I've been calling you on? I will break this, I will BREAK THIS. Damn druggie idiot. Is this what you've been doing the whole time I've been trying to reach
  you?</blockquote>
```

Comment: there are many pages so it is hard to wrap each symbol in a tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use easily like

```
.custom-font{
 font-family:any
}
```

and then

```
<div>hello there <span class='custom-font'>i am custom</span> but i am not</div>
```

Comment: This is not a solution because I need to change font for symbol in all pages on website