# How to supscript ®-symbol in h1 header?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I try to use the "®-symbol" in a generated documentation using Sphinx.

This special symbol makes some problems in headers but is working fine in normal text.

Here is my reStructuredText:

```
Name®
=====

Name®

Name<sup>®</sup>
================
```

and the result is

[image: output]

The problem here is that the "®-symbol" is placed on the baseline in all headers and is not superscripted like below in the normal text.

As you can see in the image, the `<sup>`-tag is not evaluated.

How can I get a superscripted version in the headers, too?

Comment: Does it work if you use `<sup>®</sup>`?

Comment: I did try to add this in the header, but it was not evaluated. In the generated file it was printed as string.

Comment: Isn't the position of the symbol a feature of the font? In some fonts it is superscripted; in others it's not.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32559897/407651

Comment: @mzjn It looks like you ar right. If I change the font-family, the behaviour changes, too.

Comment: While the different position of ® in headers vs. running text seems to be a font issue, the solution should be to mark it as superscript with *reStructuredText* syntax https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#superscript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sup html tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup), and then style it with css

```css
sup {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Name<sup>&#174;</sup></h1>
```

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for. Adding the `sup`-tag to does't work. Please see my changes in the question.

Comment: @mosc9575 This would be the solution in HTML/CSS, I would recommend removing those tags from your question if you don't want answers in those languages.

Comment: To get the `<sup>` tag in Sphinx's HTML output, you need reStructuredText syntax in the input (unless you configure Sphinx to use a Markdown parser).